# Where is the WordPress code that determines the order of elements of an Audio Playlist?

Tags: wordpress, audio, playlist

As shown in the picture, in the Wordpress Playlist how to simply display the current-track below the track-list — but NOT by using CSS? Where is the WP main code that determines the order of these elements?

I figured there are files such wp-playlist.js, media.php, mediaelement-and-player.js that allows you to manipulate each element/event individually, but none of them ultimately determines the order how these elements are displayed, there should be a parent code somewhere which calls and displays all these elements in this specific order. **Where it is, which code is responsible for this order?**

It may look very simple but I wasted 48 hours and still can't figure this out, maybe I am just retarded. Any WordPress expert out there, any help greatly appreciated.

WP PLAYLIST SCREENSHOT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVBsq.png

Comment: @TomaszKula There isn't any code I created, this is WP normal/default behavior, I am asking what file/code determines this behavior? MCVE is irrelevant here.